# How to set fix directory for output file in V4 Printer Driver

Tags: c++, visual-studio, printers, virtual-printer, v4-printer-driver

I am working with V4 printer driver, i need to store output xps file to a specific folder instead of letting user select output folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a render filter and use the code from Microsoft sample ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/printdocs/create-a-blank-xps-om)) in it. At the end you could use "WriteToFile" method of your XPS package to write the modified content to your specific file and folder.